# Python GUI window stay on top without focus

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to write my own on screen keyboard in python modeled after the [messagease keyboard](http://www.exideas.com/ME/index.php) which combines swipes and taps to input characters. 
I plan to use it on windows but would like to try and keep it cross platform if possible.

Currently I am trying to find a way to keep the window on top and yet keep the cursor/focus in the previous window so that when I emulate key presses (using pyautogui) they will appear in the correct window.

With tkinter I can keep the window on top with this line of code but I don't know how to keep the previous window in focus.

```
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
```

And to send key presses, I am using pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.typewrite("characters to write")
```

I don't have much experience in writing a gui in python so if it is easier to accomplish in a different framework I'm willing to switch.

So the base of my question is this:

How do I make a gui window that can be interacted with (touch, swipes, etc) but that does not take the keyboard focus away from another window/application?

Comment: Your question is very broad, in addition you comment your little experience in GUI, I recommend that you focus on a single library.

Comment: I mentioned trying different libraries and my little experience to say that I am not set on tkinter and am willing to use other libraries if they are more well suited.

Comment: That sounds like recommending library, am I right?

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. I just want to find a way to display a window on top of other windows while leaving the focus and cursor in another window. If that can be done in tinker that would be great, but if it can only be done in some other library, I am open to finding a solution in that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is windows only, but to set the style of a window with python to not get focus you can use ctypes:

```
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

GWL_STYLE = -16
GWL_EXSTYLE = -20
WS_CHILD = 0x40000000
WS_EX_APPWINDOW = 0x00040000
WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080
WS_EX_NOACTIVATE = 0x08000000

SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020
SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010
SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002
SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001

# write short names for functions and specify argument and return types
GetWindowLong = windll.user32.GetWindowLongW
GetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
GetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT)

SetWindowLong = windll.user32.SetWindowLongW
SetWindowLong.restype = wintypes.ULONG
SetWindowLong.argtpes = (wintypes.HWND, wintypes.INT, wintypes.ULONG)

SetWindowPos = windll.user32.SetWindowPos

def find_root_window(win): # takes tkinter window ref
    w_id = win.winfo_id() # gets handle
    style = GetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE) # get existing style
    newstyle = style & ~WS_CHILD # remove child style
    res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, newstyle) # set new style
    res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
    hwnd = int(root.wm_frame(), 16) # find handle of parent
    res = SetWindowLong(w_id, GWL_STYLE, style) # set back to old style
    res = SetWindowPos(w_id, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
    return hwnd # return parents handle

def set_no_focus(hwnd):
    style = GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) # get existing style
    style = style & ~WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW # remove toolwindow style
    style = style | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
    res = SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, style)
    res = SetWindowPos(hwnd, 0, 0,0,0,0, SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)

def push_me():
    print('you pushed me!')

def focus_me(event):
    root.focus_force()

root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
tk.Button(root, text="Push me", command=push_me).pack()
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Button-1>', focus_me) # if we have a widget that must have focus it needs to be bound
root.update() # for some reason, window style is messed with after window creation, update to get past this
hwnd = find_root_window(root)
if hwnd:
    set_no_focus(hwnd)
root.mainloop()
```

you need to use the right Get/Set functions depending on the applications environment. for 32 bit windows it seems you need to use either:
`GetWindowLongW` and `SetWindowLongW`
or
`GetWindowLongA` and `SetWindowLongA`

but 64 bit needs:
`GetWindowLongPtrW` and `SetWindowLongPtrW`
or
`GetWindowLongPtrA` and `SetWindowLongPtrA`
see [this](http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/78241/)